# Update react state based on i18next.language

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

As changing language doesn't force a rerender of all components in my project I tried a simple workaround by using the useState hook which takes i18next.language, and then update the state whenever i18next.language changes, however this doesn't seem to do the job.

```
  const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = React.useState<string>(
    i18next.language
  )
  console.log('The language is:', currentLanguage)
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentLanguage(i18next.language)
    console.log('Language in useEffect:', i18next.language)
  }, [currentLanguage])
```

The console printouts looks like this

```
The language is: se 
i18next: languageChanged en 
The language is: se
```

I'm sure I must be missing something really basic, but I figured it could be worth a shot asking here as a more experienced developer can probably see the fault in seconds.

Comment: there should be no need for this workaround…

Comment: just make sure you use the useTranslation hook everywhere